# php echo div class not working

Tags: php, css, class, html, echo

I am trying to echo a div class `<div class="Box">` but not working. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
     echo '<div class="Box">

     echo Anchor(T('Edit My Account'), '/profile/edit', FALSE, array('class' => 'Popup EditAccountLink'));
     echo "<br />";
     echo Anchor(T('Change My Password'), '/profile/password', FALSE, array('class' => 'Popup PasswordLink'));
     echo "<br />";

     $Inbox = 'Inbox';
     $CountUnreadConversations = $Session->User->CountUnreadConversations;
     if (is_numeric($CountUnreadConversations) && $CountUnreadConversations > 0)
     $Inbox .= ''.$CountUnreadConversations.'';
     echo Anchor(T('Inbox'), '/messages/all', 'Inbox');

     </div>'
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting on this site should answer your question perfectly. You should be using a text editor with syntax highlighting. It will greatly help you find dumb mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and last lines are wrong, missing proper quotation marks and also an echo on the last line.  It should be:

```
echo '<div class="Box">';

 .... rest of code here...

echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't terminated the string with `';`.

`echo '<div class="Box">';`

Answer (score 1):

Enable the error_reporting to E_ALL. Read on [documentation](http://php.net/error_reporting). After this, you know what is happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parse error. Enable error_reporting to E_ALL.